# Encontrar la ultima palabra de una linea en un fichero mediante expresión regular en Python

Tags: python, regex

Quiero que, mi programa imprima lineas máximo de 50 caracteres, y si esa línea contiene una o más palabras que hacen que se supere ese valor de caracteres, pasarlo a la siguiente linea, todo eso mediante expresiones regulares. Mi código, aunque simple por el momento porque me he quedado atascado, está así:

```
with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        if len(linea) > 50:

        if len(linea) <= 50:
            print(linea)
```

Comment: Porque quieres hacerlo con regex si no lo necesitas para medir el largo de una linea? Basta con usar manejo de indices. Me parece overkill obligarte a usar regex para un problema tan simple.

Comment: A ver realmente prefiero hacerlo con regex porque es como se "supone" que se debe hacer mejor, pero realmente me da igual mientras que consiga lo que quiero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas usar una expresión regular deberías hacer algo como esto: 
Te recomiendo cargar el texto completo y dejarlo en una sola linea para luego separarlo con los matches de de la expresion regular.

```
import re
allText = ""
limit = 100
with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        allText += linea.replace("\n","")

while len(allText) > 0:
    if len(allText) > limit:
        res = re.search("(^[\s*\S]{1,"+str(limit)+"}\ )([\s\S]*)",allText)
        print(res.group(1))
        allText = res.group(2)
    if len(allText) <= limit:
        print(allText)
        allText = ""
```

PD: La solución de @Vichoko debería servirte sin problemas solo debes adaptar la solución a tu código.

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que quiero, con res.group(2) obtengo las palabras que sobrepasan los 50 caracteres. Ahora tengo una duda, como paso esas palabras, a la siguiente linea del texto?

Comment: Edito mi codigo con una variable auxiliar para que funcione como deseas.

Comment: Edito nuevamente el codigo para evitar el error logico de saltarse la ultima linea.

Comment: Una duda, en la expresión regular del search, si quisiera meter ahi un limite que me pide el usuario, (es decir, no 50 que es un valor arbitrario). ¿Como sería la expresión regular?

Comment: Solo edita el 1,50 de la expresión regular, lo edite y agregué el LIMIT dentro de la expresión para que tome el valor del lineas igual. checalo.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que quieres hacer se denomina *Text Wrapping* o *Line Wrapping* en donde las lineas largas las cortas segun un largo, en general, el largo del terminal.

La verdad es que hay varias formas de resolver esto, la mas fácil es no re-inventar la rueda y utilizar el modulo [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) incluido en la librería estándar de Python.

```
line_limit = 50
with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
 all_text = file.read()
 print(textwrap.fill(all_text, line_limit))
```

Si deseas mantener la idea de arreglo de lineas, es exactamente lo que retorna la funcion `textwrap.fill`

```
line_limit = 50
with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
 all_text = file.read()
 wrapped_lines = textwrap.fill(all_text, line_limit)

for line in wrapped_lines:
 print(line)
```

Comment: Eso no soluciona mi problema. Lo que yo quiero hacer es ir leyendo linea por linea, si esa linea es mayor que la longitud corto la palabra (ojo, aqui tengo varias reglas de como cortar la palabra) y la paso a la siguiente linea. Si leo el texto entero ya no puedo ir viendo linea por linea si la longitud es mayor que 50, y mas con ese 40 tan arbitrario que has puesto tu en el textwrap, no es la solución que quiero. Solo quiero obtener las palabras de la línea que hacen que supere la longitud pedida

Comment: Amigo me equivoque en el numero, sin embargo el 40 significa el largo de la linea (en el link que puse puedes leer la documentación). De hecho, el metodo fill retorna una lista de strings o lineas por lo que al dejarlo en una variable puedes iterarlo. Agregaré un anexo para que veas como se hace y te invito a hecharle una mirada a la documentación de la librería.

Answer (score 0):

Se necesita usar [`pass`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements) para demarcar una bloque vacio. [Tambien se necesita escapar un `\` con otra `\`.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22)

```py
with open('F:\\Respaldo\\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
    for linea in f:
        if len(linea) > 50:
            pass

        if len(linea) <= 50:
            print(linea)
```

Comment: Con ese pass estas perdiendo caracteres lo cual no es bueno. En esa clausula se debería imprimir los primeros 50 caracteres y el resto acumularlo en algún lado para que la siguiente iteración se completen los 50 caracteres, si es que el largo de la linea es menor a 100. En fin, no es algo q salga en 10 lineas.