# Encontrar la/las palabra/s que hacen que se supere una longitud dada y pasarlas a la siguiente linea del fichero en Python

Tags: python, regex

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: Dada una cierta longitud que le pido al usuario, encontrar la palabra o palabras que hacen que esa longitud se sobrepase y pasarlas a la siguiente linea del fichero. Arbitrariamente uso la longitud 50 porque nose como hacer una expresion regular con la longitud dada por el usuario, y tampoco se como quitar en la linea el 'corte' que hace que la longitud sea mayor que la pedida por el usuario y pasarla a la siguiente línea.

```
longitud = str(longitud)       
with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('F:\Respaldo\quijote.txt_g','w') as file:

        for linea in f:
            if len(linea) > 50:
                res = re.search("^[\s*\S]{1,50}(\ )([\s\S]*)",linea)
                linea = res.group(0)
                corte = res.group(2)
                file.write(linea) 
                file.write(corte)
            if len(linea) <= 50:
                file.write(linea)
```

Comment: Hace un rato formulaste una pregunta casi equivalente que obtuvo respuestas (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314835/encontrar-la-ultima-palabra-de-una-linea-en-un-fichero-mediante-expresi%c3%b3n-regula). Debes mejorarla o cerrarla. Haces que las personas que voluntariamente (no les pagan por ello) invierten su tiempo en ayudar a otros, colaboren en vano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Encontrar la ultima palabra de una linea en un fichero mediante expresión regular en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/314835/encontrar-la-ultima-palabra-de-una-linea-en-un-fichero-mediante-expresi%c3%b3n-regula)